# Why is USB most commonly implemented only at 5Gbps or 10Gbps instead of 20Gbps?

Tags: usb-3

I read on https://www.cnet.com/news/usb-4-will-support-8k-and-16k-displays-heres-how-itll-work/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201228212120/https://www.cnet.com/news/usb-4-will-support-8k-and-16k-displays-heres-how-itll-work/)):

> USB 2 reached a data-transfer speed of 480Mbps. USB 3 in principle can reach 20Gbps, though it's most commonly implemented only at 5Gbps or 10Gbps today. USB 4 will be able to reach 40Gbps, the speed of Thunderbolt 3.

Why is USB most commonly implemented only at 5Gbps or 10Gbps instead of 20Gbps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is simply misleading. It is a given that “USB 3” is “commonly implemented only at 5 Gbps”. [USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) (5 Gbps) was specified 10 years ago. Uncertified products were available even earlier.

Roughly 7 years ago, [USB 3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#USB_3.1) (up to 10 Gbps) was specified.

Only just over 2 years ago, [USB 3.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#USB_3.2) (up to 20 Gbps) was specified.

It is only natural the vast majority of devices would feature 5 Gbps, simply because it has been available so much longer.

10 Gbps is also well-established by now, though not as much as 5 Gbps.

20 Gbps is not well-established. It is only available on very few motherboards. Devices are even more scarce. Bandwidth this high isn’t needed for most applications. Thunderbolt 3 is a major competitor and features high-performance PCIe access, enabling external GPUs, something USB cannot offer.

My personal take is that USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 is pointless and will never be widely used.

Comment: I would also add that everything in 10Gbps or 20Gbps probably requires more expensive hardware in pheripherial device. And there is no point to use more than 5Gbps in many devices.

Comment: I would add that going from 480Mbps USB2 to 5Gbps is a much more dramatic increase than from 5Gbps to 10, or 10 to 20. The first is a 10x jump while subsequent jumps are only 2x.  5Gbps still allows nearly 500MB/s which for storage is pretty good, but for displays may not be enough.